# Connection SQL server C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

I have Installed SQL server 2008 I want to connect to it using c# i have managed to establish connection by using tools->Connect to database but when i write connection string and try to open the connection then exception occurs "Instance Failure". what is wrong my server name is NEO-SOFT-SOL\SQLEXPRESS and connection string I used is  `@"Data Source=NEO-SOFT-SOL\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=user;Integrated Security=True";`

what is wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're using the `@` symbol, then `\\` really means two slashes, you probably want just one `\`

See the [verbatim string literals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28VS.71%29.aspx) documentation for some examples to help explain.